Dax for Text Column filtered by start and end date (Power BI)
I have a table with a list of users, start dates, and end dates.  I also have a 'between' type slicer with dates.  I want to show a filtered list of users that will allow me to see which users are enrolled between the dates in the slicer.
Trying to at least filter our the end dates:
Table is Users[User,Added,Removed]
DAX Column:
F_User = VAR FirstDay = CALCULATE(MIN(FiscalCalendar[CALENDAR DATE]),ALLSELECTED(FiscalCalendar[CALENDAR DATE])) RETURN CALCULATETABLE(Users,Users[User], KEEPFILTERS('Users'[Removed] < FirstDay))
I wanted it to return users who were still had not been removed before the start of the (sliced) calendar dates.

Can you share some data and expected output?
